# Can't see the Items of the ListBox after the code is a success itself?

Tags: vb.net

Why is it that whenever I run this code it works in the database just fine but when I look at the ListBox all of the items I put in it are gone? When I put 3 items for example then execute the code below when I check the database it updated just fine but the Listbox itself becomes empty. And it shows an error that the index is not acceptable.

Here is my code :

```
     For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

                Dim l_text As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(i))

                MysqlConn.ConnectionString = ServerString
                Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
                Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter

                Dim bSource As New BindingSource
                Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
                Dim query As String

                MysqlConn.Open()
                query = "select * from test.subject where subject_name= '" + l_text + "'"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
                READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

                While READER.Read
                    slot = READER.GetInt32("subject_slot")

                    slot = slot - 1

                    Label1.Text = ""
                    Label5.Text = ""
                End While

                MysqlConn.Close()


                MysqlConn.Open()

                query = "UPDATE test.subject SET subject_slot='" & slot & "' WHERE subject_name= '" + l_text + "'"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
                READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                MysqlConn.Close()


            Next


            MsgBox("ENROLLMENT SUCCESSFUL")
            MsgBox("ALL SUBJECTS SELECTED ARE ENROLLED")
            load_table()
```

Comment: Post code as text only please. Error messages too.

Comment: If you'd like some help you should post the actual code, no one can cut and paste an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you really thought about what you're actually trying to achieve there?  Look at these two lines of code.  Here's your loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

and here's a line that's inside that loop:

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
```

If you clear the `ListBox` on the first iteration of that loop then of course the index you use on the second iteration, i.e. 1, is going to be invalid.  Any index would be invalid because there aren't any items because you cleared.

You need to stop and think about what that loop is actually supposed to be doing.  Pick up a pen and paper and write it down if you need to but the code you have makes no sense as it is so either you haven't bothered to read/debug the code to confirm that it does what you expect or your expectations themselves are nonsensical.